# Mock.Of<T> with constructor arguments

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, moq

I have a concrete class that I am mocking using `Mock.Of`, but it does not have a default constructor. Is there any way to get this to work without having to interface this or using `new Mock`? The former is overkill at this time, and the latter is uglier. I am going to try creating an extension method that returns a `new Mock().Object`, however I do not think that `Mock.Get` will work in that scenario

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414704/mocking-objects-with-moq-when-constructor-has-parameters

Comment: I looked at that, but it does not solve my problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that Moq does track objects created normally (with `new` and pass back `Object`) so that they can be used in `Mock.Get`. So, this works for me. I would still take a built in way if there is one:

```
public static T MockOf<T>(params Object[] args) where T : class
{
  return new Mock<T>(args).Object;
}
```